# Is bash redirection of file descriptor 3 the most efficient way to read a tcp port and write to a text file?

Tags: android, linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I am logging GPS data on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian OS) by forwarding text from an Android phone connected by USB. The app ShareGPS correctly dumps several lines of text every second to port 50000. On the Pi I run `adb` to forward the port to the Pi.
From there I redirect the socket using a pseudo path to a file descriptor and then redirect the descriptor to a text file.

```
adb forward tcp:50000 tcp:50000

exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/50000

cat &3 >> dump-file.txt
```

To me this seems a very convoluted route. Is there a more efficient way record from a port on the phone to a text file on the Pi?

Phone setup and adb reference http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2145434
Socket redirection http://hacktux.com/bash/socket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need back-and-forth communications, you don't have to open a separate FD:

```
cat < /dev/tcp/localhost/50000 > dump-file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

One way or another, there will need to be a process that listens to the port and writes to the file as there is no built-in O/S function to do so.

So, really, there isn't going to be a more efficient way to run that.  You might be able to save some startup cost by turning the script into a program, but I wouldn't bother - the savings will be tiny.